# How could I pass shell script output to notification?

Tags: macos, shell, notifications, automator

I would like to show result of shell script run (`exiftool -k -P -overwrite_original_in_place -ImageDescription= "$1"/*.ARW`) in notification. I've tried to use `$1` as text in the subject, but it shows exactly $1 instead of script output.

Answer (score 5):

There needs to be a ***Set Value of Variable*** action in between the script and notification actions.

*Set Value of Variable* accepts input from previous action and assigns it to a variable with the name of your choice.

This variable is then available for other actions. Just start typing the name of the variable in a field and it should pop-up in the auto-suggestion.

[image: Automator pass script result to notification as variable.]

Answer (score 1):

In 10.9 or later, you can use the `display notification` AppleScript command:

```
osascript -e 'on run {t}' -e 'display notification "" with title "t"' -e end title
```

In 10.8 you can use terminal-notifier:

```
terminal-notifier -title title -message ''
```

terminal-notifier can be installed with `sudo gem install terminal-notifier`.

Comment: 10.9 contains built-in functionality to display notifications. Can not it show previous step result?

Comment: Looks old. why nto use Display notificatoin?